# Landau notation. Show $\omega(\Theta(f))= \Theta(w(f))$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, notation

Prove or disprove that:

a) $\forall c\in \mathbb{N}  $  $2^{cn} = 2^n $ ( disproved )

b) $\forall f,g: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ $ g= \Omega(f) \cup O(f) $ (disproved)

c)$\forall f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ $\omega(\Theta(f))=  \Theta(\omega(f))$

As you can see the last claim is my problem. I'm pretty sure that the last one is true. So

$$\omega(\Theta(f)) := \cup_{g \in \Theta(f)} \omega(g)  $$ and

$$\Theta(\omega(f)) := \cup_{g \in \omega(f)} \Theta(g)  $$

My idea is to show that $\omega(\Theta(f)) = \omega(f)$ and $\Theta(\omega(f)) = \omega(f)$, which would prove the claim, but failed.

*** Definition in general for Landau notation: ***

$ O(f) $ = { $g : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N} | \exists c > 0 , n_0 \in\mathbb{N}, \forall n \geq n_0  : g(n) \leq c \cdot f(n)$ }

$ \Omega(f) $ = { $g : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N} | \exists c > 0 , n_0 \in\mathbb{N}, \forall n \geq n_0  : g(n) \geq c \cdot f(n)$ }

$ \Theta(f) = O(f) \cup \Omega(f) $

$ \omega(f) $ =  { $ g | \lim_{ n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = 0 $ }

Comment: Can you explain your notations? What are $\Omega, O, \omega, Theta$

Comment: Sorry thought that this was clear. I will edit my question now.